How to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} \zeta(k) \zeta(n-k) x^{k-1} = x^{-1} - \psi_{0}(-x) - \gamma$ from generating function of $\zeta()$?
In equation (130) of this page, the identity $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} \zeta(k) \zeta(n-k) x^{k-1} = x^{-1} - \psi_{0}(-x) - \gamma \label{1} \tag{1} $$ is stated. Here, $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the Riemann zeta function.
It is mentioned, furthermore, that this identity can be derived from the following generating function of the Riemann zeta function: $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \zeta(k) x^{k-1} = - \psi_{0}(1-x) - \gamma. \label{2} \tag{2} $$
Equation \eqref{2} is also mentioned in equation (26) on p. 11 of the following paper (PDF) by Borwein et al.
My question is:

How does one derive equation \eqref{1} from equation \eqref{2} ?


Now cross-posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477995/finding-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-2n-2-zetak-zetan-k-xk-1-x
